# How can l get token from BitBucket OAuth

Tags: api, oauth, bitbucket, access-token

I'm trying to get a token through my OAuth application as written in the documentation, but I always get this error

> {"error_description": "Invalid OAuth client credentials", "error":
> "unauthorized_client"}

My actions:

1. I receive the code:

   [https://bitbucket.org/site/oauth2/authorize?client_id={my_application_key}&response_type=code](https://bitbucket.org/site/oauth2/authorize?client_id=%7Bmy_application_key%7D&response_type=code)
2. I want to receive a token for this code:

   curl -X POST -u "client_id: my_application_secret" https://bitbucket.org/site/oauth2/access_token -d grant_type=authorization_code -d code={code}

Maybe I'm missing something?

Answer (score 6):

Replace all your client_id and secret with the consumer key and consumer secret respectively generated from your Bitbucket Settings' OAuth.

When you've successfully authorized your integrating app and generated the access_token via: https://bitbucket.org/site/oauth2/access_token , you should receive an access_token.

Comment: To be clear, the problem is that the documentation does not clearly indicate constants to be replaced. In `-u client_id:secret` you should put your ConsumerKey and ConsumerSecret.

Comment: How to make -u client_id:secret in postman?